# Do i need .NET framework 2.0 SDK to compile from command line with .NET based compiler

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

HI
i write a code like

filename test.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()

{

 printf("Hello");
}

}
```

I have .Net Framework 2.0 installed in my computer. Compiling using **MSBuild.exe**

when i try to compile this from command line and navigated to .NET frameworl 2.0 folder using **msbuild.exe** it shows warning and error that VCBuild.exe not available install framework2.0 sdk do i really need it ???

Help me

Comment: *How* are you trying to compile this?

Comment: Even if you were trying to use the right compiler (Microsoft's C++) it still wouldn't compile, there's one brace too much. Are you sure you've got a clue of what you're trying to do at all? (like knowing the name of the language you're using)

Answer (score 1):

Try the free Visual C++ compiler, that should get you what you are looking for.

You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/#webInstall).

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a C++ compiler from somewhere, certainly - and there's no C++ compiler in the plain framework (unlike C#).

Answer (score 0):

You can't build a .net project by using only .net framework's msbuild.exe
You need to have a .net framework 2.0 SDK or you should have installed .net Studio.
Better you install visual studio express edition and use MSBuild.exe to your app without opening visual studio's IDE.